# Self invoking function inside jQuery event is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, self-invoking-function

Self invoking function defined inside jQuery event is not working, but why?

```js
$('div').on('click', function(){
  $('div').text($('div').text() + 1)
  (function(){
    $('div').text($('div').text() + 0)
  })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>text</div>
```

**Edit:**
Answers below are focused on `this` keyword so I've changed `this` parameter to `'div'`. It still does not work.

Comment: What is the purpose of the IIFE?

Comment: It works with `div` also. Check my code and change the `this` to the `div`.

Comment: Get rid of the IIFE or show a reason for needing it in the first place. No need for it in what is shown

Comment: Always add a semicolon before your IIFE. and the beginning of your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you miss a `;` at the end of `$('div').text($('div').text() + 1)`

Without the `;` it is the same as if you would write:

```
$('div').text($('div').text() + 1)(function(){
   $('div').text($('div').text() + 0)
})();
```

But because `text($('div').text() + 1)` does not return a function, you will get this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).text(...) is not a function

This is one situation where you have to use the `;` to end your statement.

[ecma-262: 11.9.2 Examples of Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-examples-of-automatic-semicolon-insertion)

> The source
>
> ```
> a = b + c
> (d + e).print()
> ```
>
> is not transformed by automatic semicolon insertion, because the parenthesised 
>     expression that begins the second line can be interpreted as an argument list 
>     for a function call:
>
> ```
> a = b + c(d + e).print()
> ```

So you have to write:

```
$('div').text($('div').text() + 1);
(function(){
   $('div').text($('div').text() + 0)
})();
```

Comment: missing `;` is irrelevant and solution will change text in all div in page, not the specific instance

Comment: @charlietfl it is not irrelevant. Because without the `;` the code will result in an `TypeError`,  because it is not an IIFE.

Comment: Huh? Sure it is. Semi colons are optional in javascript

Comment: Thanks. Now my example works. But my real code was without a typo and does not work. I'll try to find what's wrong .

Comment: @charlietfl In this particular case they are not.

Comment: Based on what? Cite a source. WHat you are saying doesn't make sense

Comment: @charlietfl I added the corresponding example of the Ecma-262 specs.

Answer (score 4):

Inside that `IIFE` the `this` refers to another context. Each function has it's own context. You can use [**arrow function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [**explicitly binding of the context**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or just keep `this` reference into another variable and use it.
One more thing, you missed to put `;` after the first statement, this will cause an error.

Also don't use this style in that code `$('div')`, this will find all divs but get the text of the first one, so you do more job than it needs.

**Arrow function**

```js
$('div').on('click', function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text() + 1);
    (() => {
      $(this).text($(this).text() + 0)
    })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>text</div>
```

**Explicit binding of the context**

```js
$('div').on('click', function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text() + 1);
    (function() {
        $(this).text($(this).text() + 0)
    }).bind(this)();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>text</div>
```

**Keep the reference into another variable**

```js
$('div').on('click', function(){
    const that = this;
    $(that).text($(that).text() + 1);
    (function(){
       $(that).text($(that).text() + 0)
    })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>text</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div').on('click', function(){
 $(this).text($(this).text() + 1);
    var divelement = $(this);
 (function(element){
   element.text($(element).text() + 0);
  })(divelement);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>text</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and is unnecessary, another answer posted here solves the problem, as well as explains it and was posted earlier.

Comment: Please check again

Comment: Checking again I see variable `element` that is undefined and see no explanation for what you are doing as in [ask]. Code only answers are not very valuable without an explanation